# How to Create two Foreign Keys in one Table pointing to the same Column in some table?

Tags: c#, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I have a database design I want to implement, which is hard and make the error "there were multiple ForeignKeyAttributes which are pointing to same set of propertie"

we have an airport and flights, a flight have a Foreign key to the airport that it's flying from, and another Foreign key to the airport the flight is going to.

but both airports are in the same table. there for the Flight table has two foreign key pointing at the same column in the Airport table

the Airport Class

```
{
public class Airport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Flight.ToAirportId))]
    public ICollection<Flight> ComingFlightsId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Flight.FromAirportId))]
    public ICollection<Flight> GoingFlightsId { get; set; }
}}
```

the flight class

```
{
public class Flight
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FromAirportId))]
    public Airport FromAirport { get; set; }
    public int FromAirportId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ToAirportId))]
    public Airport ToAirport { get; set; }
    public int ToAirportId { get; set; }
}}
```

Comment: There is no question here, what is going wrong with your code?

Comment: when i try migration the error "there were multiple ForeignKeyAttributes which are pointing to same set of propertie", appears and I don't know what's wrong

Comment: I would suggest adding this info to the question, just to make sure someone looking over it knows exactly what you need help with!

Comment: I don't think the Airport needs the `ForeignKeyAttribute`, as these are many to one links. The Airport table doesn't have a foreign key to the Flight.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars I wrote the ForeignKeyAttribute on the Airport, to make EF know which ICollection related to which Foreign Key in the Flight, as there's more than one Foreign key so more than one ICollection

Comment: You use InversePropertyAttribtue for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Just use this :

```
public class Airport
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("FromAirport")]
  public ICollection<Flight> ComingFlights { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("ToAirport")]
  public ICollection<Flight> GoingFlights { get; set; }
}


public class Flight
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int FromAirportId { get; set; }

   public int ToAirportId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey(nameof(FromAirportId))]
   [InverseProperty("ComingFlights")]
   public Airport FromAirport { get; set; }


   [ForeignKey(nameof(ToAirportId))]
   [InverseProperty("GoingFlights")]
   public Airport ToAirport { get; set; }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question.
[Inverse Property](https://entityframework.net/inverse-property)

add this annotation to the ICollection

this how the Airport class should look like in my case

```
{
public class Airport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Locatoin { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty(nameof(Flight.ToAirportId))]
    public ICollection<Flight> ComingFlightsId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Flight.FromAirportId))]
    public ICollection<Flight> GoingFlightsId { get; set; }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `virtual` modifier on `public ICollection<Flight> ComingFlightsId { get; set; }`and `public ICollection<Flight> GoingFlightsId { get; set; }` and remove `ForeignKey` attribute from them